# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TTS' but installed TTS= 0.21.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, text-to-speech

Hi everyone I'm installing [xtts-api-server](https://github.com/daswer123/xtts-api-server?tab=readme-ov-file#windows) however everything installed successfully but giving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TTS'`

my env:
`python== 3.10.6`

```
relevent pip freeze:

TTS==0.21.3
```

error:

```
(.venv) ➜ xtts git:(release) python -m xtts_api_server --streaming-mode-improve --deepspeed --stream-play-sync
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\program\SillyTavern\xtts\.venv\lib\site-packages\xtts_api_server\__main__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from xtts_api_server.server import app
  File "D:\program\SillyTavern\xtts\.venv\lib\site-packages\xtts_api_server\server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TTS.api import TTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TTS'
```

i tried to uninstall and install again but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this problem by downgrading `python` by `3.10` to `3.9`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help:

1. Restart your terminal or command prompt
2. Active your virtual environment
3. Check `pip list`(make sure the library in the response)
4. Re-run the command